# Optimizing webpack build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a problem compiling a project after saving a change in the files; the compilation time of the files takes 2 or more minutes.

To fix the problem, I took the following steps:

1.In babel-loader from the documentation in the option object for properties cacheDirectory set to true, cacheComprassion to false
2. In the ts-loader from the documentation in the option object for the properties transpileOnly and happyPackMode set to true
3.dev-tool disabled for better performance
4. ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin connected to check types in typescript
5. Code splitting customized

Webpack config file

```
const path = require('path');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.tsx'),
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader', options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
              happyPackMode: true
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            // creates style nodes from JS strings
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            // translates CSS into CommonJS
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            // compiles Sass to CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: [
                // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
                require('autoprefixer'),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader'],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            // creates style nodes from JS strings
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            // translates CSS into CommonJS
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg/,
        use: {
          loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  // devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'app',
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
    minimize: true,
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', 'scss'], modules: ['node_modules'] },
  output: {
    // path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    // filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/hmr/',
    chunkFilename: '[id].js?v=[chunkhash]',
  },
  devServer: {
    stats: {
      // assets: true,
      // cachedAssets: true,
      // performance: true,
      // entrypoints: true,
      // chunkGroups: true,
      // chunks: true,
      // chunkModules: true,
      // show modules contained in each chunk
      // chunkOrigins: true,
      // show the origin of a chunk (why was this chunk created)
      // chunkRelations: true,
      // show relations to other chunks (parents, children, sibilings)
      // dependentModules: true,
    },
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: '/hmr/',
    filename: 'app.js',
    // hot: true,
    // hotOnly: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      typescript: {
        diagnosticOptions: {
          semantic: true,
          syntactic: true,
        },
      },
      async: true,
    }),
    new ESLintPlugin({
      eslintPath: 'eslint',
      fix: true,
      quiet: true,
      extensions: ['ts', 'tsx'],
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
};
```

Please tell me how you can reduce the compilation time of files in the project after saving the files?

Comment: The solution might be as easy as delete Webpack, install [Parcel](http://parceljs.org).

Comment: Thanks for advising parcel, but the project uses webpack and I need to look for a solution for it.

Comment: Webpack is notoriously slow and apart from buying a faster computer there's really not much you can do about that. This is why I recommend Parcel, it's generally a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. The problem turned out to be in the eslint-loader-webpack plugin. If you install the old version of eslint-loader, then everything works fine.

How to solve the issue of the eslint-loader-webpack plugin slow?